# Find Contours OpenCv using c#

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a image of number plate ,now i want to segment this into individual characters.To achieve this i have tried to implement FindContour .Web has  many links for this but these are mosly in c++.I need it in C#.I am facing problem in passing 
parameters to this function.

Code:

```
      private void segment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        IplImage src = Cv.LoadImage("plate.jpg", LoadMode.GrayScale);
        IplImage dst = Cv.CreateImage(new CvSize(src.Width, src.Height), BitDepth.U8, 1);

        CvMemStorage memory = new CvMemStorage(0);

        CvSeq* contours;


        Cv.FindContours(src, memory, &contours, ContourRetrieval.External,ContourChain.ApproxSimple);
}
```

Exceptions:

> Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe
>   context.
>          Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type    ('OpenCvSharp.CvSeq')
>   'OpenCvSharp.CvPoint' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: do yourself a favour, and switch to emgu , instead of using that gross api

Comment: I dont have enough time to shift on emgu.